# Replacing middle n characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a phone number and I want to display it like censored form. For example I have: `+923451234567`

I want to display it like: `+923*******67`

**Str.replace** function will be used, but how:

```
var str = '+923451234567'
str.replace(i_Dont_Know_What, '*');
```

So in this case string contains 13 characters. And I want to replace 5th-11th character with **" * "**

I have found this somewhere, but this is not what I want.

```
var str = "name(replace these parenthesis by @)domain.com";
var patt1 = /\(.*@\)/i;
document.write(str.replace(patt1,"@"));
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: So what rule do we have if it's 12 / 11 / 14 characters?   Why 5th-11th in this case..?

Comment: it will be 13 characters, always. As (in this case) mentioned in question. :)

Comment: `As (in this case)`  means, as in this case. not another case.  eg.  If I drink too much, in this case I get drunk, if I drink a few pints I don't.  IOW; your question was implying the rules changed if it was not 13 characters.

Comment: Need to mention that privacy should never rely on client-side scripts ? I hope it's for server-side code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nice and simple one line replace with a substring match, no need for a messy regex here.

```js
var str = '+923451234567';
console.log(str.replace(str.substring(4,11), "*******"));
```

Comment: Perhaps messy was the wrong word, but not everyone likes or is that comfortable using regex, so i just wanted to give an alternative.

Comment: Not everyone likes it because it works correctly only for this given example. It may bug if you change the masking range, like: `"+123123555".replace("+123123555".substring(4,6), "**")` will result in `+**3123555`, but this is not what's expected.

Answer (score 7):

Multple ways of doing it, one way is a simple reg expression

```js
console.log("+923451234567".replace(/(\+\d{3})\d{7}/,"$1*******"))
```

Comment: Hi, @epascarello. If I have a dynamic string and I want to replace it then what is your suggested regex. For example: "BwcAsizDxqjQwc0zLs8=" and I want it to be "Bwc************=". But the string can be anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

regex to keep 3 num characters at the beginning and 2 at the end

regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/xR6pRD/1

```js
var str = '+923451234567'
str = str.replace(/(\+?\d{3})(\d+)(\d{2})/g, function(match, start, middle, end) {
  return start + "*".repeat(middle.length) + end;
});

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamic approach by giving the length and take an offset for shifting the replacement charcters.

```js
function replaceMiddle(string, n) {
    var rest = string.length - n;
    return string.slice(0, Math.ceil(rest / 2) + 1) + '*'.repeat(n) + string.slice(-Math.floor(rest / 2) + 1);
};

console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 7));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 6));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 5));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 4));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 3));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 2));
console.log(replaceMiddle('+923451234567', 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First we get the substring to be replaced:

```
//you can use variables here too
var substringToBeReplaced = num.substring(4, 11); //4512345
```

then we replace the substring in the string:

```
var str = '+923451234567'
str.replace(substringToBeReplaced, '*******'); //result will be +923*******67
```

you can use another range instead of `4 - 11` if you want other set of numbers to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '+923451234567';
var lol = str.replace(/^(\+?[\d]{3})\d+(\d{3})$/g,"$1*****$2"); 
console.log(lol);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just reconstruct a new string like so

```
replaceWithStar(index1,index2, str) {
    return str.substr(0, index1) + '*******'+ str.substr(index2, str.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it is a complete method.

```
 setStar(val) {
        let value = val.split('');
        let centerVal = value.slice(3,7);
        return value.slice(0,3).join("") + centerVal.map(()=> "*").join("") + value.slice(7,11).join("");
      }
```

i hope useful.

Answer (score 0):

For non fixed str length:

```
function mask_str(str, visible_start = false, visible_end = false){

        let strlen = str.length;

        visible_start = visible_start?visible_start:2;
        visible_end = visible_end?visible_end:2;

        return str.replace(str.substring(visible_start,strlen-visible_end), "*".repeat(strlen-visible_start-visible_end));

    }
```

Needs some tweaks to compensate if str is short and e.t.c.

Answer (score -2):

```js
console.log("+923451234567".replace(/(\\d{3})\d{7}/,"*"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Did you run the snippet you posted?